# Как при обновлении страницы router vue.js 2.0 запустить определённую функцию?

Tags: vue.js

Как при загрузке страницы узнать путь роутера vue.js и выполнить параметры?
Пример.
Есть ссылка site/users/:UserId
когда выбираешь юзера- подгружаются его данные. 
Но если обновить,то не могу при старте подвязать функцию обновления.
Тоесть если выбран роутер site/users/:UserId и страница стартовала, то надо выполнить запрос к серверу, а не только, когда клацаешь по данной ссылке.
Как такое реализовать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Из документации, можно назначить сторожевой хук непосредственно в компоненте:

```
const Foo = {
  template: `...`,
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {

    next(vm => {
    // инстанс компонента доступен как `vm`
  }
})
```

Т.е. можно привязать обработчик, который будет срабатывать при переходе на данный компонент и далее, после подтверждения навигации, срабатывает next, в котором можно получить доступ к компоненту.

Answer (score 0):

Метод mounted() вызывается сразу после того как экземпляр был смонтирован.

Тут [Lifecycle-Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте при перезагрузке страницы сделать вызов функиции, допустим так
вы создаете функицию в JS в котор будет находиться vue код, а в html напишите, что при загрузке вызывать эту функцию и все, работы на 3 минуты

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае скорее всего поможет следующее:

```
 mounted() {    
  // здесь будет вызываться функция запроса на сервер. Поле id будет вытягивать id из пути страницы, вот таким образом this.$route.params.id     
}
```